# Representation for Vandermonde's permanent

Tags: matrices

Permanent of a matrix A = $\|a_{i,j}\|_{i,j=1}^{n}$ is defined as
$$
   \mathrm{Perm}(A) = \sum\limits_{\sigma \in S_{n}} a_{1,\sigma_{1}},\ldots,a_{n,\sigma_{n}}
$$
Is there some representation for permanent of Vandermonde's matrix similar to its determinant?  Is there some numerical methods for computing Vandermonde's permanent that uses the particularity of Vandermonde's matrix?

Comment: No, but i have to evaluate it using computer. In general, I can use Ryser's formula ($O(n2^n)$ operations), but it doesn't use the particularity of Wandermonde's matrix.

Comment: [An apropos paper](http://www.emis.ams.org/journals/AMEN/2006/050915-3.pdf). (At least you can bound your permanent...)

Comment: @J.M.ain'tamathematician Fixed link:
https://www.emis.de/journals/AMEN/2006/050915-3.pdf
Jia-jin Wen and Zhi-hua Zhang
Vandermonde type determinants and inequalities
Appl. Math. E-Notes, 6(2006), 211-218

Comment: Muirhead inequality will also give bounds to the "Vandermonde-permanent".